# composer and satis tags for testing and prod

Tags: composer-php, satis

We're using composer, satis and SVN to manage our in-house PHP libraries.
We commit changes to SVN trunk during development, then tag versions (following semantic versioning) when they're ready for testing.
Once a library version is tagged, we can use composer as part of our deployment to the testing environment. Following successful testing, we'd then deploy that same version to production.

The issue here, is that once we've tagged a version for testing, we have to be very careful as the newly tagged version will be picked up by composer when preparing the next prod release.

What I'm imagining, is that we'd tag a version as a beta or RC, (eg v1.1RC1) and somehow configure our deployment process such that it will refuse to deploy an RC or beta to production. If a version is tested successfully, we'd re-tag that version as a released version (v1.1RC1 -> v1.1) and release that.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are saying, I understand that you are actually afraid of tagging a new version of a library because that code could actually be used and break that other application, right?

One approach would be to do good testing. I don't see it should be a problem to tag a version of a library. If the tests are all green, there should be no reason not to tag it. This would work even if the tests are basically only "let's see if it works, manually".

Now the second step is to integrate that new version into the application: Run `composer update` and see if the application is still running, i.e. start all the tests and wait for green.

I guess it might be a good idea to have a separate area where you check out the application, intentionally run `composer update` to fetch all the newest libraries, run all the tests and report that a) there are updates and b) they work. A developer should then confirm the update, i.e. do it again manually and commit the resulting `composer.lock` file, or grab the resulting lock file from that update test.

I don't think there is benefit in using non-production release versions. You have to deal with the next version anyways - constantly toggling the minimum stability setting or adding `@RC` or `@beta` flags to the version requirements of the library don't really help.